# Getting defined substring with help of sed or egrep

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Everyone!!
I want to get specific substring from stdout of command.
 
**stdout:**

> {"response": 
>   {"id":"110200dev1","success":"true","token":"09ad7cc7da1db13334281b84f2a8fa54"},"success":"true"}

I need to get a hex string after token without quotation marks, the length of hex string is 32 letters.I suppose it can be done by **sed** or **egrep**. I don't want to use **awk** here. Because the stdout is being changed very often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing json with sed and awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk)

Comment: @triplee It isn't duplicate because i try to get this substring without Perl expressions

Comment: I do not understand the reason to not to use `awk`, please explain better.

Comment: @Jotne API is developing, because of it every week i need to change my script 
     'gawk '{ print substr($0,58,32)}''

Comment: @BilowYuriy : `awk` is not limited to just using `substr` ;)

Comment: @BilowYuriy `awk` supports regex, and `gnu awk` support lots of stuff.

Comment: @Idriss Neumann , yes, i see it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an alternate `gnu-awk` solution when `grep -P` isn't available:

```
awk -F: '{gsub(/"/, "")} NF==2&&$1=="token"{print $2}' RS='[{},]' <<< "$string"
09ad7cc7da1db13334281b84f2a8fa54
```

Comment: Yep.Thank you, it works!!
       gawk -F: '{gsub(/"/, "")} NF==2&&$1=="token"{print $2}' RS='[{},]'

Answer (score 4):

**grep**'s nature is extracting things:

```
grep -Po '"token":"\K[^"]+'
```

- `-P` option interprets the pattern as a [Perl regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).
- `-o` option shows only the matching part that matches the pattern.
- `\K` throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.

Or an option using `sed`...

```
sed 's/.*"token":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: I perform my script in MinGW, there aren't Perl patterns there :(

Comment: MinGW doesn't have **egrep** :( .

Comment: Well you should state your question and what is available more thoroughly next time.

Comment: Ok. i will, thank you for your help, by the way your script with **sed** doesn't get me result, Cyrus's response was acceptable

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
your-command | sed 's/.*"token":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
YourStreamOrFile | sed -n 's/.*"token":"\([a-f0-9]\{32\}\)".*/\1/p'
```

doesn not return a full string if not corresponding